# Counting and then updating array

Tags: php, dynamic-arrays

I have a database with a date field that I want to count the number of unique years and then how many entries for each year. Here is what I have:

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql_result)) 
{
     $Date = $row["Date"];
     //DETERMINE YEARS
     $Year = substr("$Date",0,4);
     if (!in_array($Year, $allDates)){
          $allDates[] = $Year;;
     }
```

}

So this leaves me with an array containing all the unique years.

```
Array ( [0] => 2010 [1] => 2008 [2] => 2009 [3] => 2006 [4] => 2007 [5] => 2012 [6] => 2011 [7] => 2013 )
```

Now how do I loop through all the entries again and total up the number of records with that specific year?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Why not just do this with a COUNT and a GROUP BY in your SQL query? `select YEAR(myDateColumn) AS 'year', COUNT(1) AS 'count' FROM myTable GROUP BY YEAR(myDateColumn)` and the number of unique years is the number of rows returned

Answer (score 0):

Instead of looping again, you can maintain the count for each year in same iteration.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Bharat

Try something like that :

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql_result)) 
{
     $Date = $row["Date"];
     //DETERMINE YEARS
     $Year = substr("$Date",0,4);
     if (!array_key_exists($Year, $allDates)){
          $allDates[$Year] = $allDates[$Year]+1;
     }else{
          $allDates[$Year] = 1;
     }
}
```

Comment: Cool. This seems to work with the exception that it leaves me with this:

    Array ( [0] => 771 [1] => 1277 [2] => 1379 [3] => 372 [4] => 1703 [5] => 1473 [6] => 1006 [7] => 1671 )

And I need to know the dates that correspond to the totals

Comment: The date (I mean the year) is present as a key of your array. array_keys($allDates) will return you the years' list.

Answer (score 0):

I would like to add to the answers of @Bharat and @Odward, there is a function in php called `array_count_values()`. You can read about it in PHP docs : 
http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-count-values.php
You can use this function :

```
$result = array_count_values($Year);
print_r($result);
```

The output should be something like this :

```
Array
(
    [2012] => 2
    [2009] => 4
    [2010] => 3
)
```

I hope this helps and excuse my English.

Comment: Thanks Guys. I laid in bed all last night trying to figure this out - shoulda just asked ;)